# How to move and delete all files and subdirectories with command line in windows7?

Tags: windows-7

I am looking for a way to move all files and subfolders within a given directory to somewhere else and after the movement delete the original folder. For example, suppose in current path, there is a folder called FOLDERA, I am trying to move all files and subfolders from FOLDERA to the current path and then remove FOLDERA, but I need to do this with a command line. I try MOVE command but I find that it can only move the files. Anyway to do that? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
del /s *.* should do the work in windows 7
```

Answer (score 2):

On Windows Vista or later, look at `robocopy`

NOTE: This question is off topic for Stack Overflow; [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/) or [Super User](https://superuser.com/) would likely be a better fit.

Answer (score 0):

```
Robocopy <src> <dest> /MOVE
```

will move the files and delete the original directories.

There are several other options that you may wish to use to control overwriting etc.